# How do you apply Filter Logging to Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have created an App Service (.NET 5.0) that logs to Application Insights.

The logging is setup in my startup.cs as follows:

```
     public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
     {
         services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry( Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"] );
         services.AddLogging( builder =>
         {
             builder.AddApplicationInsights( Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"] );
             builder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>( "", LogLevel.Warning );
             builder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>( "Microsoft", LogLevel.Error );
             builder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>( "MyApp.ClientAPI", LogLevel.Debug );
         } );
```

I also have the same settings in my appsettings.json:

```
"Logging": 
{
     "LogLevel": 
     {
         "Default": "Warning",
         "Microsoft": "Error",
         "MyApp.ClientAPI": "Debug",
     }
 }
```

In the Azure Portal, on the "App Service Logs" page of the App Service, I have Application Logging (Blob) Level set to Verbose.

The log files contain verbose output from everywhere. The above settings are ignored.

I can filter the logs with the following query:

```
traces
| where operation_Name startswith "POST Appointment/MyWebHook"
| extend category = customDimensions.CategoryName
| where (severityLevel > 1) or (category startswith "MyApp")
| project timestamp, message, severityLevel, category, customDimensions
```

However, this doesn't prevent huge numbers of Microsoft Trace and Debug messages being stored.

How can I create log files that contain debug messages from my code, but only warnings/errors from system code?

**The following is the answer from the link below:** (by AnuragSingh-MSFT)

The App Service Logs can't be filtered. To get the application insights filtering working I needed the following settings in my appsettings.json:

```
    "Logging":
    {
        "ApplicationInsights":
        {
            "LogLevel":
            {
                "Default": "Warning",
                "Microsoft": "Error",
                "MyApp.ClientAPI": "Debug"
            }
        }
    },
```